# Android canvas: drawText indents and wraps off rectangle

Tags: android, canvas

I'm making an interactive story editor for Android, and my current task is to make objects with text.

How can you restrict canvas.drawText to a specific rectangle and make the text wrap off edges similarly to CSS property `white-space: normal;`?

Currently:

[image]
(same effect in CSS)
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this class solves the problem: https://gist.github.com/markusfisch/2655909#file-textrect-java